# How do I parse JSONp response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm new(ish) to Javascript and am trying to grab data from an Extrernal API from another website, parse it and display chunks of it in my HTML page. Currently, everything works, all except to the point where I attempt to grab the information from the JSONp response in order to update the HTML display.

The JavaScript code that I'm using:

```js
//Fetch method grabs information from "myURL"
fetch("https://exampleURL.com", {
    mode: 'cors'
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) //Checking if response is returned correctly
    {
      var res = response; //Storing response in a variable
      jQuery000000000000000_0000000000(res); //Sending response parsing function
    }
  });


//Parsing function reads the 'title' data from the JSONp response
function jQuery000000000000000_0000000000(res) {
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = res[0].title; //Error occurs here
}
```

And the JSONp response I'm supposed to be getting from the external API:

```js
jQuery000000000000000_0000000000([{"isSuffix":false,"name":"name","title":"Mr"}]);
```

Whenever I run this code, I get a "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" error in the console, referencing the innerHTML line in my code above.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! :)

[EDIT] From what I've read from other answers online, I thought it was appropriate to create a function with the same name as the one in the response (jQuery000000000000000_0000000000(res);). I am unsure if this is correct.

The response comes from an external website. Thanks!

Comment: What is your html page? Looks like it doesnt have 'title' in it

Comment: @IStepashka Na... Not HTML page, it's the `res` object. You didn't understand what happened.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's a JSONP request. You just need to call the `<script>` file when you need it.

```
<script src="/path/to/jsonp.js"></script>
```

The script is an executable one. So you don't need to use AJAX or any sort to call it. And see, how you are sending your `res`? You are doing it wrong. It's because you already have the correct call in the response:

```
jQuery000000000000000_0000000000([{"isSuffix":false,"name":"name","title":"Mr"}]);
```

The above code needs to just execute. Don't use `fetch()`.

Your complete code should be:

```
<script>
  //Parsing function reads the 'title' data from the JSONp response
  function jQuery000000000000000_0000000000(res) {
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = res[0].title; //Error occurs here
  }
</script>
<script src="/path/to/jsonp.js"></script>
```

Another way to do the above inside script is by using:

```
//Parsing function reads the 'title' data from the JSONp response
function jQuery000000000000000_0000000000(res) {
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = res[0].title; //Error occurs here
}
$.getScript("/path/to/jsonp.js");
```

The content in the above file will automatically call the `jQuery000000000000000_0000000000(res)` function with valid parameters. `:)`

---

**Detailed Explanation**

In your current code, what happens is, you do an AJAX call to the JSONP request, which you shouldn't do, and it makes your code this way:

```
jQuery000000000000000_0000000000("jQuery000000000000000_0000000000([{"isSuffix":false,"name":"name","title":"Mr"}])");
```

When it tries to access the title property of the first element, which is a string, here, it will be `undefined`. Because, a string will not have a title property.

Here's the stack:

```
jQuery000000000000000_0000000000(jQuery000000000000000_0000000000([{"isSuffix":false,"name":"name","title":"Mr"}]));
res = jQuery000000000000000_0000000000([{"isSuffix":false,"name":"name","title":"Mr"}]);
res[0] = undefined;
res[0].title = TypeError;
```

And this is the reason you are getting undefined... `:)`

Comment: So sorry, I didn't mention that my code fetches the JSONp from an external source, so I do not have the call function locally. I've edited my question. Apologies!

Comment: @Jesse Can you explain the whole code that's there with you here?

Comment: Pretty much my fetch function fetches the API from here (http://services.runescape.com/m=website-data/playerDetails.ws?names=%5B%22X%22%5D&callback=jQuery000000000000000_0000000000&_=0) Which returns the JSONp response as described in the question. I wish to then parse my response to a HTML id. The fetch works as my console tells me, and the innerhtml code also works, however I am unsure of how to implement my response properly to pass the "title" value from the response. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jesse If you can show the whole code, I can try solving it and helping you.

Comment: I have uploaded it here: https://pastebin.com/wZJSmF8u. Again, thanks for helping!